# iPhone not detected by Xcode 11 but is recognised by Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode11

I currently have Xcode 11.6 installed on macOS Catalina 10.15.3, and I am attempting to test an app on my iPhone 6S (iOS 13.6.1)

However, Xcode fails to recognize the device. My Mac does recognize it, as it does appear in the System Report, yet on Xcode it says:

> no devices connected to "my Mac"

[image: System Report]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This worked me, you can try this**

1. Quit XCode
2. Disconnect device
3. In your terminal sudo launchctl stop com.apple.usbmuxd
4. Relaunch Xcode
5. Connect the device

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to check as below:

- Check your phone have been trusted.
- Check your phone open developer mode.
- Try another cable.

Comment: How do you open developer mode if Xcode is not recognizing the device?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run it on your device and not on simulator make sure Xcode supports the iOS version installed in your device.
I know for a fact that Xcode Version 11.6 (11E708) supports ios 13.6 but I am not sure if it supports 13.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Xcode 11 doesn't always install the iOS 13.6.x platform code. To see if this is the problem, you can check if Xcode has installed the 13.6 platform, by looking in this folder:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

This may not be your issue, because the device should still appear in Xcode's "Devices and Simulators" window (from the Window menu) and show an error message saying the platform is not supported.

If 13.6 doesn't exist (in this folder), then you can download it from this third party github repo:

> https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

However with the release of iOS 13.7, Xcode 11 seems to now download and install the 13.7 platform code correctly. So if you can skip 13.6.x, then upgrade your device to 13.7 and Xcode 11 should correctly recognise it again.

And obviously upgrade to the latest Xcode, which is now (as I write this) 11.7.